# VBA reordering columns from different workbook or sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reorder column headers with their data with another dataset with the correct order. So, I'm trying to go from Bad:"a,c,d,b" to Good:"a,b,c,d" with their headers + data then pasting it on a blank sheet, Fixed. The code runs but, it doesn't print out values on the new sheet. Column length of the data is a different length so the extra headers would be placed at the end.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OrderColumns()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, gws As Worksheet, bws As Worksheet, header As String
    Dim gcols As Long, bcols As Long, c As Range, i As Long, fcol As Long

    Set gws = Worksheets("Good Columns")
    Set bws = Worksheets("Bad Columns")
    
     gcols = gws.Range("MD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
     bcols = bws.Range("MD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(Before:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Fixed"
    End With
    
    fcol = 1
    
    For i = 1 To gcols
        
        header = gws.Cells(1, i)
        
            With bws
            Set c = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, bcols)).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            End With
            
            If (Not c Is Nothing) Then
                Cells(1, c.Column).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Fixed").Cells(1, bcols)
                fcol = fcol + 1
            End If

    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Where this was written from this code since I wasn't defining variables along with using select statements:

```
Sub Rearange_Column_Order()

    Sheets("Bad Columns").Select
    i = Sheets("Bad Columns").Index
    
    Sheets.Add
    Sheets(i).Name = "Fixed"
    
    gcols = Sheets("Good Columns").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    bcol = Sheets("Bad Columns").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    fcol = 1
    
    For i = 1 To gcols
        header = Sheets("Good Columns").Cells(1, i)
        Sheets("Bad Columns").Select
        Set c = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, bcol)).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If (Not (c) Is Nothing) Then
            Cells(1, c.Column).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Fixed").Cells(1, fcol)
            fcol = fcol + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: All Cells/Range calls should ideally be qualified with a worksheet reference.  Inside your `With bws` you don't scope anything to `bws`  (missing the leading `.`)

Comment: `Cells(1, c.Column).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Fixed").Cells(1, bcols)` did you mean to copy to column `fcol` not `bcols` ?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, maybe you want to try something like this : `Set g = gws.Range("MD1", gws.Range("MD1").End(xlToLeft)): Set b = bws.Range("MD1", bws.Range("MD1").End(xlToLeft)): Set f = ws.Range(g(1, 1).Address)` g is the good header range, b is the bad header range, f = is the start of the cell of the fixed one. Then `For Each cell In g: Set c = b.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)` this loop to each cell in good header range and get the position to the found looped cell value in bad header range. (continue)

Comment: `If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Copy f: Set f = f.Offset(0, 1): Next` ---> it copy the entire c.column to f then set f to the next cell to the right, then continue the loop, which is to the next cell of the good header range.

Comment: You could avoid a loop entirely and simply use a lesser-known aspect of the [Advanced Filter](https://youtu.be/evrnIuDRtsQ) function to re-order your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub OrderColumns()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, gws As Worksheet, bws As Worksheet, header As String
    Dim gcols As Range, bcols As Range, c As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, f As Range, pasteDest As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'use a specific workbook for all sheets...
    Set gws = wb.Worksheets("Good Columns")
    Set bws = wb.Worksheets("Bad Columns")
    
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    ws.name = "Fixed"
    
    Set gcols = gws.Range("A1", gws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    Set bcols = bws.Range("A1", bws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    
    Set pasteDest = ws.Range("A1") 'start pasting here
    For Each c In gcols 'loop over "good" headers
        'find in "bad" headers
        Set f = bcols.Find(what:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            'if found, copy whole column
            f.EntireColumn.Copy pasteDest
            Set pasteDest = pasteDest.Offset(0, 1) 'move one column over
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```